# Which is the best Space Marine Battles novel? Which should I read next?

Tags: books, warhammer-40k

I have recently started reading Warhammer 40,000 Space Marine Battles books,

Ive read The Battle of The Fang and Architect Of Fate. I really liked both of them, but I'm not sure which one to choose next.

Are they all equally good? Anyone have any suggestions on which one I should choose next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALL of them are good:

Personal FAV:

Armageddon and Flesh of Cretacia and Legion of Damned

It is basically up to you and the depth of your pocket!

You can read them in any order

Comment: My question has been 'put on hold as off-topic', so obviously I'm asking in the wrong place. But cheers for ur input Cherubel, I'll check those three out!